# Split function in SSIS Expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I got a column values as '035-7448-001-3854535'
In SSIS - Data Flow i need to split this into three different components as

```
**Col1                Col2                  Col3**
  035               7448-001               3854535
```

this can be done using script component.

Is there a way to deal with this in Derived Column Component

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you could do this with a combination of [FINDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx) and [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137541.aspx) functions, but I think a script component will ultimately yield a more readable, better documented solution.